# How do you print out the results from WITH ROLLUP or GROUPING SETS in PHP?

Tags: php, sql

I can't find anything that has example code.

Whenever I have a SQL statement that uses WITH ROLLUP or GROUPING SETS, how do I print that out in my PHP code?  I know how to get rows and echo them, but not the totals.

If it matters, I have access to Oracle, SQL Server, and MySQL.

edit:  Does anyone have an example they could point me to?

Comment: `with rollup`, doesn't that just add another row? I've never used it in php, but I assume the answer is in the last row...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is absolutely no difference between rows which contain aggregate values in resultset and 'normal' from application point of view (I mean types are the same, they all belong to one resultset).  DB Engine will add one or more extra rows with aggregate information and `NULL`s as values for grouping column . RDMS may provide extra features to help differentiating normal `NULL`s from `NULL` values returned by `ROLLUP` (for instance, `GROUPING` in SQLServer).

Comment: But how do I show the rollup value?  I know how to get it from the main select clause.

Comment: For instance, you have `SELECT product_category, sum(price) as price FROM table1 GROUP BY product_category WITH ROLLUP` . You iterate through result set on client side, and then `product_category` is null, output string "Total for all categories", otherwise output value of this column. I hope I understood your question right.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get totals for each of your rows you need to have some kind of aggregate function.
For instance look at an example in oracle's documentation for rollup ,
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/F49540_01/DOC/server.815/a68003/rollup_c.htm#32084

As you can see from the results once you add an aggregate function, that column is your totals. If you want to get only the grand totals, you can filter out non null values for the other columns.